# proguard does not stop obfuscating method name despite "Keep names"

Tags: java, proguard

I have following set up for keeping class and class method names. It works well with classes hence classes in package and sub packages of `com.seleniumtests.**`  are not obfuscated.

[image]

But despite I have selected `Keep names - .class method names` check box, methods in classes of package `com.seleniumtests.**` are still obfuscated.

Did I miss any configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox for `Keep names - .class method names` is unrelated. It preserves the names of classes that are used in `.class` constructs, for instance `MyClass.class`. It is rarely required.

The screenshot doesn't show the custom rules that you have defined, but the configuration should contain

```
-keep class com.seleniumtests.** {
    <methods>;
}
```

You can verify this on the `Process` tab or in the saved configuration file.

Comment: I ended up using config file and not GUI. Thanks for answer and congratulations on bounty :)