# Keep method name from Obfuscator Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

How can I prevent method **`SendToGroup()`** from Obfuscator in proguard.

Coz, this method name will be call from server side and need to be same name (dynamic method call). It's a push from signalR.

```
public class main {

    private class inner implement x {

        @Override
        public Object dynamic {

            return new Object {

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void SendToGroup(String message) {
                    androidNotification(message);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505353/keep-a-method-from-obfuscate-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263311/proguard-does-not-stop-obfuscating-method-name-despite-keep-names) but still not work and not understand.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep an interface in progourd use the -keep public interface statement.

For example:

```
-keep public interface com.your_package_name.class_name$someInterface {*;}
```

In order to keep a class member in progourd use the - keepclassmembers statement.

For example:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.project.inner {
    private static void someclass(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: For the annotations use: -keepattributes *Annotation*
For the interface use: -keep class com."Package name"."Interface name" {
  public *; 
} 
The public * - is to allow all public methods using proguard.

or:

-keep public interface com.your_package_name.class_name$someInterface {*;}
to allow it on the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

annotate the method with @Keep

Comment: @Keep public void SendToGroup(String message) {